# how to set custom file properties for a file using google drive api in C#

Tags: c#, api, google-drive-api

I am trying to set some custom file properties to some files that I am uploading to google drive using the API. I am doing this in dot net using C#. I saw a sample code in the net as follows:

```
{
  'key':        'additionalID',
  'value':      '8e8aceg2af2ge72e78',
  'visibility': 'PRIVATE'
}
```

But this code is giving me compile error (Syntax error at ":"). My code is below:

```
string myMimeType = GetMimeType(FileName);
System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileName);
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
     body.Title = info.Name;
     body.Description = info.Name;
     body.MimeType = myMimeType;
     body.Editable = false;
     body.Shared = true;
     body.Properties = new List<PropertyList>() {
                "key": "myspecialID",
                "value": "test123456",
                "visibility": "PUBLIC" };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which "." is throwing the error? Also, this just an observation a `new List<PropertyList>` seems to be a `List` of a `List`... is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the V2 API for [File](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1File.html) and [Property](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1Property.html) it looks more like this is how you would add properties to `File` `objects`. The structure you saw on this page was just a psuedo outline of the properties.

```
body.Properties = new IList<Property>() {
    new Property() { Key = "myspecialID", Value = "test123456", Visibility = "PUBLIC" }
};
```